# how to insert values to table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i try to insert values to my table, it doesn't work and i get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "regular"
LINE 2: ('100', 'Astronomy Today', '1st publisher', 6, 'regular', 4/...
                                                                   ^
```

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Subscribes
(cid numeric(5,0),
title varchar (30),
publisher varchar(30),
period integer, 
offer varchar (10), 
sfrom date,
primary key(cid, title, publisher, offer, period),
foreign key(cid) references Customer(cid),
foreign key(title, publisher,offer, period) references Pricing(title, 
publisher,offer, period));


INSERT INTO Subscribes VALUES
('100', 'Astronomy Today', '1st publisher', 6, 'regular', 4/4/2015),
('100', 'Bridal Guide', '3rd publisher', 12, 'regular', 1/5/2015),
('100', 'Click Magazine', '3rd publisher', 6, 'regular', 20/12/2014),
('107', 'Bridal Guide', '3rd publisher', 12, 'regular', 29/4/2015);
```

PS: I've checked every variable and couldn't find the problem

Answer (score 1):

Place single quotes around date like below

```
INSERT INTO Subscribes VALUES
('100', 'Astronomy Today', '1st publisher', 6, 'regular', '2015/4/4')
```

Answer (score 0):

someone was faster than me :)

```
 CREATE TABLE Subscribes       (cid numeric(5,0), title varchar (30), publisher,varchar(30), period integer, offer varchar (10), sfrom date ....
 INSERT INTO Subscribes VALUES ('100'           , 'Astronomy Today' , '1st publisher'      , 6           , 'regular'           , 4/4/2015)  .....
```

you have problem inserting date field, its not quoted ... and its format is not well formed. you should use standard system format,  '2015-04-04' or use to_date(text, text) conversion function from text to date inside insert.

Answer (score 0):

When using `INSERT`, you should take care with the code you write:

- Always list the columns explicitly.
- Don't wrap numbers in single quotes.
- Use the proper format for date constants.

So, it should look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO Subscribes(cid, title, publisher, period, offer, sfrom)
     VALUES (100, 'Astronomy Today', '1st publisher', 6, 'regular', '2015-04-04'), . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a date you should use TO_DATE

The following insert should work for your case:

```
INSERT INTO Subscribes(cid, title, publisher, period, offer, sfrom)
VALUES (100, 'Astronomy Today', '1st publisher', 6, 'regular', TO_DATE('04/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`29/4/2015` is not a valid date literal. Either use a proper ANSI literal: `date '2015-04-29'` or use the `to_date()` function (I prefer ANSI literals, because it's less typing)

And `'100'` is not a number it's a character literal. Number don't need single quotes. Use `100` instead.

You should also always qualify the column names to make the statement more robust:

```
INSERT INTO Subscribes  (cid, title, publisher, period, offer, sfrom)
```

Putting all together this results in something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Subscribes 
  (cid, title, publisher, period, offer, sfrom)
VALUES 
(100, 'Astronomy Today', '1st publisher', 6, 'regular', date '2015-04-04'),
(100, 'Bridal Guide', '3rd publisher', 12, 'regular', date '2015-05-01'),
(100, 'Click Magazine', '3rd publisher', 6, 'regular', date '2014-12-20'),
(107, 'Bridal Guide', '3rd publisher', 12, 'regular', date '2015-04-29');
```